# Vagrant Apache setup on Windows 10

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am having a hard time getting Vagrant to work on Windows 10. Here is what I have done so far:

1. Installed Git 2.7.4
2. Installed VirtualBox 5.0.16
3. Installed Vagrant 1.8.1

I want a pre-configured Apache / PHP box, so I am using 'Scotch Box' (https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-box). I have cloned the repo and ran `vagrant up` from the Git Bash prompt.

This successfully created and booted up the VM, however there was a few errors during the process:

```
Installing the Window System drivers
Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.
An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions 5.0.16
Some functionality may not work as intended.
In most cases it is OK that the "Window System drivers" installation failed.
```

After this I ran `vagrant ssh`, this presented me with the Ubuntu intro screen.

I then tried to access the IP address `http://192.168.33.10` in my browser, as suggested. However this just brings up a `404 Not Found` page. I then ran `curl localhost:80` within the VM, this also outputs the same 404 page.

What exactly is going on and how can I diagnose this further? I am not too familiar with Unix so could do with some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was after some Googling.

I had a look at the `000-default.conf` file in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory. In here it had the `DocumentRoot` set as `/var/www/public`.

So all I had to do was create a new folder called `public` on my host machine and put all my website files in there.

Comment: Oh glad you got it sorted. For future reference, you can always check what `.conf` files apache is using and what directories it is reading out of by running `apache2ctl -S` (in your Guest).

Answer (score 1):

The error you listed in your question:

```
Installing the Window System drivers
Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.
An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions 5.0.16
Some functionality may not work as intended.
In most cases it is OK that the "Window System drivers" installation failed.
```

Is actually from a Vagrant plugin, `vagrant-vbguest` in my experience - which is trying to match your Guest Additions version to your virtualbox version. It is usually harmless.

More to your question, I see a few questions a week about people having issues with the scotchbox. If all you need is apache2 and php5, why not just init a trusty box and install apache2 and php5 packages?

```
vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
```

Add the following to your `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y apache2 php5
SHELL
```

You will also need to enable a network type in your `Vagrantfile`, so you can access the box from your Host (and browser). Choose one of the below to **UNCOMMENT (remove the `#`)** from the generated `Vagrantfile`:

```
# config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

or

```
# config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

Run `vagrant up` and you can access your webserver at `http://192.168.33.10` or `http://localhost:8080`, depending on which networking option you went with.

Comment: Thanks for this, really helpful. Just wondering, does private network offer any advantages over port forwarding (or vice-versa)?

Comment: Allegedly no, but I prefer the IP way because occasionally bugs come up with the port forwarding option pinning my MBP CPU usage at 100% due to some networking race condition.